# remove all negative elements from an array buffer of integers in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a question about coding. There are similar types of questions in the database which I came across but none of them clears my doubt. I am going thru the book of "Scala for Impatient".  The code below removes negative elements from the Array and gives positive elements as output

```
val a = ArrayBuffer(-1, 1, 0, -2, -1, 2, 5, 6, 7)
val positionsToKeep = for (i <- a.indices if a(i) >= 0) yield i
for (j <- positionsToKeep.indices) a(j) = a(positionsToKeep(j))
a.trimEnd(a.length - positionsToKeep.length)
```

It gives the output as (1,0,2,5,6,7) removing all negative elements.
I am unable to understand line 3 & 4.

```
for (j <- positionsToKeep.indices) a(j) = a(positionsToKeep(j))
a.trimEnd(a.length - positionsToKeep.length)
```

I'm scratching my head since 2 days on these 2 lines but can't give up and I finally posting it here seeking some help.

Comment: Line 3 and 4 are populating arraybuffer a again where 1st line is putting values of positionToKeep into a and line four is trimming array a which for the element which are left in array a.

Comment: `a.filterNot(_ < 0)` :)

Comment: `a.filter(0.<=)` is even four characters shorter, but unfortunately, it too does not work in-place, and allocates a new buffer instead (@Tim)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, they all create a new buffer of some kind, but at least `filter` is functional. This seems to work in-place `a.trimEnd(a.length - a.fold(0){ case (i, v) => a(i) = v; if (v < 0) i else i+1 })` but dodgy to update the collection you are folding!

Comment: @Tim Not all solutions have to create a new buffer. The whole point of the original example was that the filtering happens in-place inside `a`. The `trimEnd` also works in-place, and modifies `a`. The `positionsToKeep` is an annoyance - it can be easily avoided by merging lines 2 & 3, so no extra space would have to be allocated at all.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Can you explain that last bit? Not sure how to combine those two lines to avoid using extra space. (Clearly the example I gave does not use extra space and is `O(n)`)

Comment: @Tim `def filterInplace[A](buf: ArrayBuffer[A])(p: A => Boolean): Unit = {
  val n = buf.size;
  var i = 0;
  for (j <- 0 until n) {
    val a = buf(j);
    if (p(a)) {
      buf(i) = a;
      i += 1
    }
  }
  buf.trimEnd(n - i)
}` needs three `int`s on the stack, and no allocations on the heap. You can indirectly derive that `O(n)` in-place algorithm must exist, because it's essentially the same as single `partition`-step from in-place quicksort with `pivot=0`. I wouldn't consider `a.filter(_ >= 0)` in-place, because it allocates new buffer for the result.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Hmm... more like a re-implementation than "easily [] merging lines 2 & 3". I'll stick with my algorithm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a is a bufferArray so we can change the values of the array a.

Line 3:

Line 3 is populating or you can say updating the value of positionToKeep into a.

```
a(j) = positionToKeep(j)
// which is running like this 
// a(0) = positionToKeep(0)
// a(1) = positionToKeep(1) .... and so on
```

Now what will happen after populating all the values of positionToKeep into a there might be the case some older values remains untouched. Line four is deleting or dropping these elements. In the case when we have all the positive values in array a line four has like no use but when the length of a is greater then positionToKeep then we need line 4.

Line 4: consider the scenario

1. `val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

   Then our positionToKeep will have all the element and the length of both the array will be equal.

   ```
   val positionToKeep = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
   ```

   In this case line four trimEnd(0) because length of a and positionToKeep are equal.
2. `val a = Array( 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, 8, 9, -3)`

   In this case we will have `Array(1,2,3,4,8,9)` in positionToKeep

In line 3 we will update array a and after updating before line four this is how our array a will look like. 
`Array(1,2,3,4,8,9,8,9,-3)` as we need values only up to length 6 as we have only 6 positive values. We need to drop last 3 element that what is tripEnd doing for us.